# Pass callbacks with managed parameters and return types between managed and unmanaged C++

Tags: c++-cli

I am writing a native C++ project with a managed C++ wrapper that can receive and invoke callbacks from C#. The managed side should be able to retrieve back that callback and trigger on the managed environment as well.

The signature of the said callback is:

```
// Native C++
typedef EvaluateResult (*NativeFunction) (std::vector<EvaluateResult> args);

// Managed C++ wrapper
delegate EvaluateResultWrapper^ ManagedFunction (List<EvaluateResultWrapper^> args);
```

The `EvaluateResultWrapper` is the managed wrapper class for the native class `EvaluateResult`. The conversion between the `EvaluateResult` is:

```
EvaluateResult result;
EvaluateResultWrapper^ wrapper = gcnew EvaluateResultWrapper (result);

result = EvaluateResult (*wrapper.original);
```

I want to implement the constructor `EvaluateResultWrapper::EvaluateResultWrapper (ManagedFunction^ func)` that can roughly do the following:

```
// NOTE: Pseudo code
void EvaluateResultWrapper::EvaluateResultWrapper (ManagedFunction^ func) {
    this->func = func; // Store the func as a member to avoid GC

    // original is the pointer to the EvaluateResult that this object is wrapping around
    this->original = new EvaluateResult ([&func](std::vector<EvaluateResult> args) -> EvaluateResult {
        List<EvaluateResultWrapper^>^ argsList; // Convert args from vector to List. Assuming it is done under the hood
        EvaluateResultWrapper^ wrapper = func->Invoke (argsList); // Invoke the managed callback
        return EvaluateResult (wrapper.GetOriginal ()); // Convert the managed result to the native counterpart
    });
}
```

I know the above code will not work, but the idea I should be able to wrap the *managed callback* with codes that able to do conversion of both the *callback arguments and return types*, so that it is *native friendly*.

Ideally, I can also do the other way around (not important)

```
// NOTE: Pseudo code
ManagedFunction^ EvaluateResultWrapper::GetFunction (ManagedFunction^ func) {
    // if the callback is set by the managed side, return the same callback back
    if (this->func != nullptr) return this->func;

    // Otherwise, the callback is a native one
    NativeFunction nativeFunc = this->original->GetFunction ();

    return gcnew ManagedFunction ([&nativeFunc] (List<EvaluateResultWrapper^>^ args) -> EvaluaResultWrapper {
        std::vector argsList;  // Convert the args from List back to vector. Assuming it is done under the hood
        EvaluateResult result = nativeFunc (argsList); // Invoke the native function
        return gcnew EvaluateResultWrapper (result); // Convert the native result into the managed one
    });
}
```

I wonder whether this can be done?

---

**A little bit of context**: I am writing an external scripting system on native C++ for our games (similar to Lua scripting). The `EvaluateResult` is a class representing an evaluation result of any statement. It is basically a value coupled with the type. The type can be either number, boolean, string, array, object, or in this case: function callback.

The function callback can be either set within the native C++ (when the interpreter pass the user-defined function in the scripts) or a function set by the host (managed side).

The idea is the host (C# side) should be able to define and set functions into the memory (defining `print()` function to print into the host console for example). The callback is wrapped as an `EvaluateResult` class before storing into the the scripting memory.

For inspection purpose, C# side must be able to get the function callback. Therefor, the ability to get the function is nice to have (but not important, since I can always instruct the native side to execute the function for me)